# Encrypt multiple TextBox with For function C#

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I need encript multiple values from Textbox, this must happens when I close the window. It works like this.

```
private void frmUser_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] encryted = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtIp.Text);
        txtIp.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encryted);

        byte[] encryted2 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtUser.Text);
        txtUser.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encryted2);

        byte[] encryted3 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtPass.Text);
        txtPass.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encryted3);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration("C:\\conf.ini");
        conf.IniWriteValue("Info", "Ip", txtIp.Text);
        conf.IniWriteValue("Info", "User", txtUser.Text);
        conf.IniWriteValue("Info", "Password", txtPass.Text);

    }
```

But, How can I make a "For" function, for not to write much code?

**EDIT**
Here is the encrypted file.

[image]

Comment: `ToBase64String` and/or `Encoding.GetBytes` not encrypting data. Anyone with access to Google could figure out how to reverse it. It is almost equivalent to translating a phrase from English to Spanish, a non Spanish speaker might have trouble but if the user can determine that its Spanish then they could translate it with the help of the internet in a matter of seconds. Also define `For` function? What do you mean by that?

Comment: No need for a loop. Your code is simple and easy to understand. Using looping in a list of controls searching for specific textbox control would make it more complex.

Comment: @Fabricio Koch, yeah, but I have a lot of TextBox, the code above is just an example.

Comment: Just to prove my point here is your data from your above file: `Password: 12345, User: admin, Ip: 192.168.10.246`. I had to write 0 code to do this, just plugged it into https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: user: admin pass:12345

Comment: @Leinad, so you can create a loop with your form/page.Controls. For example: `foreach(Control c in this.Controls)`. Then you cast your control c as textbox.

Comment: @Igor, oh man, I have no idea, I have to change encryption method then. Thank you for that point.

Comment: Encryption requires a key and that key must be kept secret, that last part is not easy. If there is no key there is no encryption, just encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a List of byte[]

for example :

```
List<byte[]> List = new List<byte[]>();
```

then add your elements to the list

```
List.Add(encryted1) ...
```

then use a `Foreach` loop as :

```
Foreach(byte[] b in List)
{
b = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtUser.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a lot of textboxes according to your comment. 
Grab them like this.

```
        var myControls = this.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        //Gets all the textbox controls on form, you can filter it more by name if you want
        var myTextboxes = myControls.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox));


        var dictValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach(var textbox in myTextboxes)
        {
            //Encrypt textbox value
            var encryptedValue = Encrypt(textbox.Text.ToString());

            //You can specify what you want for the Key rather than textbox name also.
            dictValues.Add(textbox.Name, encryptedValue);
        }

        var conf = new Configuration("C:\\conf.ini");
        //go through dictionary
        foreach(var item in dictValues)
        {
            //write key and value
            conf.IniWriteValue("Info", item.Key, item.Value);
        }
```

Here is the encryption functions for AES256 that you can use to encypt/decrypt your data

```
    //AES256 Encryption, add your own key
   private string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "PUTKEYHERE";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
     //Decryption
    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "PUTKEYHERE";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText= Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```